# Reading specific line of the file

Tags: c++, file, getline

In the following code, I am reading a file in a loop line by line. I want when the **func** is called inside the while loop then the file should be read from the next line where it ended last time in while loop. I have seen solutions where a counter is set for counting lines inside loop but is there any other efficient method to read the file from specific line.

```
    void func(){

    int counter=0;
    ifstream file("file");
    string str;

    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {

    //some code

    func();
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `func()` recursively inside a while loop is probably not such a clever idea. Just increment `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that remembers the offset within the file and then advances to that location, but that would probably be a bad solution.  Instead, open the file outside the function and pass the stream into the function (by reference or pointer).